# Media-Query is not working completly on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design, media-queries, tablet

I used media query to put my Homepage from Smartphone to Tablet and for this I used the size of a iPad 1/2.

After I finished my Website (for Tablet) it was looking fine on my Acer Tablet but on my Girlfriends iPad its completely messed up because its seems like its not loading the Tablet Version.

Is my Media-Query wrong but if this is the Problem why is it on my Acer Tablet fine?

```css
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
```

If you want I can put in pictures of the fail iPad Version of the Homepage

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening due to the devise orientation (Portrait, Landscape).
[iPad screen sizes](http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-design-cheat-sheet-volume-2)